# How to get a single view of all my calendars?

Tags: windows, calendar, windows-8, google-calendar

On my iPhone, the Calendar app gives me a unified view of all my calendars: personal iCloud, family iCloud, google calendar that I share with someone and the Exchange calendar from work. I've seen a similar setup on Android.

I've tried doing the same thing on my desktop PC (Windows 8.1) in Outlook and it doesn't really work well. For one, I can't seem to edit either iCloud or google calendars - it only gives me a read-only view. I've also tried Thunderbird and that works even worse

Does a Windows application exists that replicates the unified calendar view like I have on my phone?

P.S.  I found a method that works, thought it is really cumbersome.  I've installed a MacOS into a virtual machine (lots of tutorials on YouTube), and I am using the Calendar app on it.  It supports everything that the mobile app supports and is nice to look at as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to pay almost $50 for that, VueMinder is one of the most complete Windows Calendar programs http://www.vueminder.com/Default.aspx

Comment: It looks good, but I don't see support for iCloud calendars.  And to get Exchange support, I need to buy the $80 version.

Comment: @AngryHacker right, my bad. But I can't find something else